# Group with at least 2 subgroups of order $p$ has at least $p^2-1$ elements of order $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$  be a finite group and $p$ be a prime number. Let $a,b$ be two elements of order $p$ such that $b\notin \langle a\rangle $ where $\langle a\rangle $  denotes the subgroup generated by $a$.

> Prove that $G$ has at least $p^2-1$ elements of order $p$.

Now $\langle a\rangle $  will have $p-1$ elements of order $p$ and since $b\notin \langle a\rangle $ if we consider $\langle b\rangle $  then we also have $p-1$ elements of order $p$. Thus $G$ has $2(p-1)$ elements of order $p$.

But I will have to prove that there are $p^2-1$ elements of order $p$.

Please give some hints to complete the proof

Answer (score 3):

If $a$ and $b$ commute they generate a subgroup isomorphic to $Z/p \oplus Z/p$ which contains $p^2-1$ elements of order $p$.

The other option is that repeated conjugation by $a$, applied to subgroup $\langle b \rangle$, creates $p$ isomorphic and distinct copies of that subgroup.  The copies have $p^2-p$ elements of order $p$. The additional $(p-1)$ elements of order $p$ come from $\langle a \rangle$ which cannot have nontrivial intersection with the copies.

We have broken the symmetry between $a$ and $b$ here.  Can more [than $p^2-1$ ] elements of order $p$ be produced by using $b$ to conjugate the group generated by $a$?  It looks true in the non-commuting case.

Comment: Sounds like what you are really trying to say is: call them $P$ and $Q$, either they commute and there is $P\times Q$ or they don't and there is the action of $Q$ on the conjugates of $P$ which must have orbits of length $1$ or $p$.

Comment: Ok after reading it a few times, this is exactly what you are saying :-) You seem to be stuck on the last bit: it cannot happen that $P^q=Q$ since then $P=Q^{q^{-1}}=Q$ ($Q$ is abelian). So $Q$ provides the additional $p-1$ elements.

Comment: Is that in reference to the third paragraph or the last sentence of the second?

Comment: +1 for a correct and complete solution. I just feel like like pointing out that even in the non-commuting case it may not be possible to get more than $p^2-1$ elements of order $p$. Consider $p=2$ and $G=S_3$. We have $aba^{-1}=bab^{-1}$ in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I had originally written some nonsense at the end (see revisions) about "as long as G is not a semidirect product" but in light of your counterexample example maybe it's not 100 percent nonsense. @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: @zyx Ah that comes from me misunderstanding your last paragraph... I thought the last paragraph was meant to signify that there is a small argument missing which explains the last sentence of the second paragraph. But never mind that, I +1'ed you earlier already :)

Comment: Edited to differentiate the two.  It's a bit surprising to have to break the symmetry and I was wondering if the argument or the $p^2-1$ bound can be improved by using both $a$ and $b$ in the same ways.  @Myself

Comment: Can you please explain what is meant by "repeated conjugation by a" and how are $p^2-p$ elements of order $p$ produced?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: think about what will be the order of $ab$, where $a\in \langle a \rangle$ and $b\in \langle b \rangle$

Comment: If a and b commute, I proved it below. However, I have temporarily deleted the post. If you would like to see at least that part of the answer, please reply.